# ActionBarsherlock how to set dividers on menu items with icons only

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem, divider

Hello android developers,
I know this question have been asked many of times, and I have also tried many solutions but they are not working for me.
Firstly I am using action bar sherlock library to show action bar,and I want to show dividers between menu items with icons only.
For that I create custom style for showing divider but they are not showing.

`<style name="Theme.SherlockCustom" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">`

`<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/actionbar_seprator</item>`

`<item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>`

`</style>`

And also tried to update sherlock library ActionMenuItemView.java for ActionBar where needsDividerBefore() will always give true. But this patch also not worked for me. Please help where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You are probably trying this on a device with Android > 4.0. The patch you mentioned is only applicable for Android < 3.0 because on later versions the native action bar implementation is used which you can't modify.

Comment: @matthias tons of thanks. Now I understood where I was going wrong. Can u please suggest how to get dividers in android > 4.0. Is there any solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get dividers on versions > 4.0 for your scenario unless you use a custom view for your action bar; the native implementation controls the behavior internally and doesn't give any hook to modify that.

HTH,
Ali.